# Retrieve value of an output parameter and assign it to a List<Model> using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I am invoking a stored procedure which updates the table in Oracle DB and then using an output parameter of `SystemRefCursor`, I am running the select query for it.

I am using the `ExecuteRawSql` extension method in Entity Framework Core to invoke the stored procedure which updates the DB and also fetches the value for the `SystemRefCursor` output parameter.

How to retrieve the value from the SystemRefCursor and assign it to a `List<Model>`?

Example :

I have a stored procedure `ProcessEmployeeRecords` which updates the `Employee` table where `DeptId = 1` and also returns the rows from the `Employee` table where `DeptId = 1` as an output parameter, namely `employeeCursor` of `SystemRefCursor` type.

How to retrieve the value from `employeeCursor` and assign it to a `List<Employee>` named `employeeList` ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

I am not familiar with retrieving value from an output parameter of `SystemRefCursor` type and assigning it to a `List<Model>`

Comment: If you're not bothered about database-portability, just get a reference to the `OracleConnection` via `(OracleConnection)dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection()` and use ADO.NET directly with `OracleCommand` and `OracleParameter`. (FWIW, EF _can_ handle procedures for you, but you need to use custom scaffolding templates to generate the `DbContext` methods - there's a lot of edge-cases involved, so often it really is easier just to use ADO.NET directly because there's zero value gained from EF' abstractions here.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! 
People will have a way easier time helping you if you provide the code in the question. 
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problem/error messages you get from your attempts.